# Как передать Bitmap из Fragmet в Activity?

Tags: android, bitmap

В приложении есть окно с изображением и внизу экрана есть кнопка установить как обои, это изображение храниться во фрагменте а кнопка расположена в активити. При нажатии на кнопку установить - запускается поток, куда попадет наш Bitmap в метод doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) - но в него приходит null.

**PageFragment**

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER = "arg_page_number";
    private int pageNumber;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        PageFragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
        pageFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return pageFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, null);
        ImageView resultView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.result_image);
        resultView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        bitmap = resultView.getDrawingCache();
//        bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) resultView.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); // not work
        resultView.setImageResource(pageNumber); // also not work
        return view;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
case R.id.setForce:
                new TaskSetWallpaper(MainActivity.this).execute(bitmap);
                break;
```

Каждый раз когда я передаю bitmap для установки обоев, получаю ошибку :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.app.WallpaperManager.setBitmap(WallpaperManager.java:778)
```

Как правильно передать Bitmap из PageFragment в MainActivity?

Answer (score 3):

Всем спасибо за помощь, в данном случае мне помогло решение передачи Bitmap с помощью интерфейса. Я создал интерфейс во фрагменте (в родительском Activity необходимо имплементировать этот интерфейс) и передал через параметр в метод этого интерфеса Bitmap, также в onAttach() не забыть типизировать(привезти) Activity к интерфейсу, и наконец в родительской Activity в переопределенном методе записываю Bitmap в глобальную переменную и затем эту переменную передаю в мой метод execute(), в общем предоставляю часть кода ))

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String TAG = PageFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private int pageNumber;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private EventListener eventListener;

    interface EventListener {
        void onSetImage(Bitmap bitmap);
    }

    static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        PageFragment pageFragment = new PageFragment();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
        pageFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return pageFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity a) {
        super.onAttach(a);
        if (a instanceof EventListener) {
            eventListener = (EventListener) a;
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(getResources().getString(R.string.error_event_listener));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, null);
        ImageView resultView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.result_image);

        resultView.setImageResource(pageNumber);
        resultView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) resultView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        eventListener.onSetImage(bitmap); // pass bitmap to parent Activity
        return view;
    }
}
```

in method onCreate() of MainActivity:

```
        int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(IMAGE_POSITION); // from recyclerview adapter

        pagerAdapter = new PreviewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.preview_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

Переопределенный метод интерфейса:

```
@Override
public void onSetImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    mBitmap = bitmap;
}
```

И место где передаю в фоновый поток:

```
case R.id.setForce:
                new TaskSetWallpaper(PreviewActivity.this).execute(mBitmap);
                break;
```

И в заключение, т.к. я использовал в своем приложении FragmentStatePagerAdapter для адаптера ViewPager, в Bitmap записывается и передается в родительскую активность 3 изображения по очереди, 1 - это текущее, 2 - предыдущее, 3 - следующее, учитывайте это, как вы понимаете запишется и передастся не текущее изображение а следующее - создал продолжение темы [Как получить текущий Bitmap из Fragment?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/661523/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-bitmap-%D0%B8%D0%B7-fragment)

Answer (score 1):

Так с ходу и не разобраться с Вашим кодом :)

Может ошибка кроется в том, что, судя по представленному коду, Вы сначала пытаетесь, получить `Bitmap` из `ImageView`, а потом уже устанавливаете `Bitmap` в `ImageView`, а значит достаточным будет лишь поменять местами строчки и написать их в следующем порядке:

```
ImageView resultView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.result_image);
resultView.setImageResource(pageNumber);
bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) resultView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Хотя тогда можно было бы сразу по `Id` ресурса достать нужный `Bitmap`:

```
Drawable drawable = getContext.getResources().getDrawable(pageNumber);
bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
resultView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

А может быть у вас переменная `pageNumber` - это совсем не `Id` ресурса, а какой-то используемый не по назначению "номер страницы", который вы пытаетесь передать в метод `setImageResource`, который не возымеет эффекта, если не найдёт такого `Id` среди `R.drawable.`. А потому у Вас в итоге содержится `null` в качестве `Drawable` внутри `ImageView`.

Будь это `Id` ресурса, переменная скорее называлась бы `mDrawableResId`, а по нынешнему названию и способу её применения суть переменной не ясна.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте получить ссылку на кнопку из активити в самом фрагменте:

```
Button setForce = ((Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.setForce));
```

Затем у этой кнопки реализуйте метод `onClick` там же во фрагменте, и в методе `onClick` загружайте изображение.

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new TaskSetWallpaper(getActivity).execute(bitmap);
        }
    });
```

Comment: попробовал, но к сожалению та же ошибка - почемуто передается null