# Как получить текущий Bitmap из Fragment?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-viewpager

При передачи Bitmap из фрагмента в активити обнаружил такой баг - я использую FragmentStatePagerAdapter для ViewPager, когда открываю изображение в отдельном окне, то записывается 3 страницы фрагмента ViewPager, 1 - это текущая, 2 - предыдущая, 3 - следующая, и получается что запишется и передастся не текущее изображение а последнее третье. Способ установить viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0) - не работает.
Вот логи:

```
D/PreviewActivity: onCreate a
D/PageFragment: newInstance fragment
D/PageFragment: newInstance fragment
D/PageFragment: newInstance fragment
D/PageFragment: onAttach fragment
D/PageFragment: onCreate fragment: 2130837590
D/PageFragment: onAttach fragment
D/PageFragment: onCreate fragment: 2130837589
D/PageFragment: onAttach fragment
D/PageFragment: onCreate fragment: 2130837591
D/PreviewActivity: onSetImage a
D/PageFragment: onCreateView fragment: 2130837590
D/PreviewActivity: onSetImage a
D/PageFragment: onCreateView fragment: 2130837589
D/PreviewActivity: onSetImage a
D/PageFragment: onCreateView fragment: 2130837591
```

Код из фрагмента:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate fragment: " + pageNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, null);
        ImageView resultView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.result_image);

        resultView.setImageResource(pageNumber);
        final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) resultView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        eventListener.onSetImage(bitmap, pageNumber); // pass bitmap to parent ActivityBug
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView fragment: " + pageNumber);
        return view;
    }
```

Когда в данной активити будем делать свайп вправо-влево, я каждый раз буду получать либо следующее изображение страницы, либо предыдущее, т.к. оно всегда будет перезаписываться, как мне всегда получать текущее изображение страницы, чтобы потом его передать в родительскую активити?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы используете наследников `ListFragment`, то в Вашему классу-наследнику можно вынести `Bitmap` в поле класса и добавить `getter` для него:

```
public YourFragment extends ListFragment {
    ...
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    ...
    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return mBitmap;
    }
    ...
}
```

Предположим Ваш `Activity` держит ссылку на `ViewPager`. Тогда следующим шагом внутри используемой `Activity` устанавливаете Вашему `ViewPager` следующий `Listener`:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        FragmentStatePagerAdapter adapter = 
                (FragmentStatePagerAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter();
        YourFragment currentFragment = 
                (YourFragment) adapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, position);
        Bitmap currentBitmap = currentFragment.getBitmap();
        // вот текущий Bitmap внутри Activity, используйте его в своих целях
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, хороший способ, отлично работает если перелистывать страницы ViewPager, но к сожалению не работает, когда мы первый раз открываем изображение - т.к. здесь мы получим null, я думаю это изза жизненного цикла андроид... как же тогда получить этот чертов Bitmap при первом открытии изображения?))

Comment: все понял, при первом открытии отработает только метод `onPageScrolled` поэтому перенес код для получения текущего Bitmap из `onPageSelected` в него и все заработало как надо))) еще раз спасибо!